# Redirect Subdomains to Wordpress Pages

Tags: url-rewriting

How can i redirect all subdomains to wordpress pages?

Like;

**blog.example.com --> example.com/blog**

**x.example.com --> example.com/x**

**video.example.com --> example.com/video**

I found some solutions but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Search in `HTTP_HOST` for characters preceding the main host name and add those as request URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I put this code to .htaccess file in wordpress directory. It doesnt work.